# How to combine multiple types of the same component in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I couldn't make a better question title but I hope I will provide clean details of what I am trying to achieve.
Let's assume I have `<SomeComponent />`.

```
interface IProps {
  label: string;
}

export const SomeComponent = (props: IProps) => {
  return /* Something */
}
```

And we have a component that handles `drag and drop` for the application and accepts `DropTarget`.

```
interface IDropSourceProps {
  isDropped: boolean;
  /* Other props */
}

interface IDnDProvider {
  DropTarget: React.ElementType<IDropSourceProps>;
}

export const DnDProvider = ({DropTarget}: IProps) => {
  return <DropTarget isDropped={isDropped}>
}
```

Typescript is throwing an error when I am passing DropTarget to DnDProvider

```
<DnDProvider DropTarget={SomeComponent} />
```

> Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
> Type 'IDropSourceProps' has no properties in common with type 'IProps'.

As you notice I am trying to combine 2 prop types ( One belongs to the actual Component itself, and the other is getting passed through the DnDProvider ).

As the DndProvider is a core component in my case I would like to handle the types separately from the actual application. But seems like it's impossible to retrieve the `DropTarget` prop types.
The other solution for me is to extend the `SomeComponent` props with `IDropSourceProps`.

```
interface IProps extends IDraggableSourceProps {
  label?: string;
}
```

I would like not to expose the core component types to the parent levels.
Is there any other solution to this situation?

Comment: How *are* you supposed to give `DropTarget` its props?

Comment: That's the case.I thought for a second about generic props, but we are not using SomeComponent props outside of the component itself.